# Power Calculations in studies to find the normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, statistical-power

If I am conducting a study to find the normal size of something e.g. part of a babies brain by measuring lots of normal brains, do I need to do a power calculation to find the sample size I need? And if so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a random sample of normal brains, then you can get an estimate of the size of a region with any sample size.  The larger your sample, the more precise your estimate will be.

You can figure out the relationship using power analysis. Exactly how to do this is software dependent and software questions are off topic here.

However, you can do some "by hand" using the formula for the standard error of the mean:
$$ s_{\bar{x}} = \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$

where s is the standard deviation and n is the sample size.

Comment: Could you clarify how power analysis might be software-dependent?

Comment: @whuber I just meant that how you do it is software dependent - in the obvious way, e.g. that in SAS you would use PROC POWER. etc.